# How to add custom Layers in ConvNext Small?

Tags: deep-learning, pycharm, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

How to add custom layers after specific layer of ConNext small?
below is the link of github code of ConvNext Small https://github.com/facebookresearch/ConvNeXt

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding which layers you would like to add and where?

Comment: I added a block of layers at the end of 4th stage in ConvNext Small. Then i checked its layered architecture its added at the right place where i wanted but when I train it with pretrained weights the error comes

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ConvNeXt:
 Missing key(s) in state_dict: "custom_block.conv.weight", "custom_block.conv.bias", "custom_block.bn.weight", "custom_block.bn.bias", "custom_block.bn.running_mean", "custom_block.bn.running_var".

Comment: Can you share the code that you've used to add layers and load pretrained weights?